# Review queue shows an empty blue box when reaching the daily upvote limit

Tags: bug

I recently reached the limit of daily upvotes and to my suprise the review queues of **late answer** and and **first answers** disappeared.

[image]

In the details of the **late answers** it informs me that I reched the daily vote limit, but the **first answer** only show a blue box.

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: That's not really tex.se specific. This was already reported on main meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370834/the-review-queues-page-shows-an-empty-blue-box-below-the-first-answers-queue